# What if there was no future.isDone check in the invokeAll method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future

If we check the invokeAll method in AbstractExecutorService class, then we can see that following things are happening:

1. Submission of the tasks in a for loop
2. Running of another for loop. And in case the future is **not completed** , then do a get on it (to make sure that all the futures are finished before returning from the invokeAll method)

If we check the get method in CompletableFuture, then we see that the get method will return the result immediately if the computation is complete, else will wait until the result is available.

My question is - is the check in point (2) for **checking the completion status** using isDone() method of future redundant? Would there be no effect if we remove this check?

Comment: Good question. As far as I can say the isDone check looks really like being redundant.  The only reason I could think of would be when the isDone call was less expensive (volatile boolean perhaps) then the get call (lock / wait synchronization?) but to be fair I am only guessing as do not have the source code at hand.

Comment: Thanks Michal, the isDone method indeed checks whether the result variable (which is volatile) is not-null. The get method otherwise looks to be more expensive (as it involves certain checks, though does not look to be synchronized)

Comment: tryAcquireShared is the "synchronization," it will block until either it times out or the Future is completed.

Comment: The `isDone()` check is made before the timeout check. Since the `finally` block will attempt to cancel all jobs on timeout, the pre-check ensures that if all futures are already done, but iterating and checking takes to much time, it will still complete the check, avoiding another iteration making a cancellation attempt.